# How to audit methods in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, audit

I am writing a Spring Boot Application. I want to audit methods with my annotation `@AuditMetod`: For example I have method `foo()` with the annotation:

```
@AuditMetod(name = "SomeValue")
foo() {...}
```

I want to handle and audit such methods like this (the simplest example):

```
auditMethod(Method method) {
    if (method.hasAnnotation(AuditMethod.class)) {
        System.out.println (method.getName() + " was called at " + new Date())
    }
}
```

**upd**

Thanks to @Karthikeyan @Swapnil Khante  and @misha2048 I understood, that I need to use AOP. But I have 2 problems:

1. The only method in Aspect class in not being called and I don't see the inscription "----------ASPECT METHOD IS CALLED-----------" in log
2. How can I check in aspect method what method it is intercepting. To get an instance of Method class.

Now I have the following code:
Controller:

```
@PostMapping
    @LoggingRest(executor = "USER", method = "CREATE", model = "SUBSCRIPTION")
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid @RequestBody SubscriptionRequestDto dto) {
       ...
    }
```

Aspect:

```
`@Aspect
@Slf4j
@Component
public class AuditAspect {
@Pointcut(value = "@annotation(com.aspect.annotations.LoggingRest)")
public void auditMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) {
    log.info("----------ASPECT METHOD IS CALLED------------");
}`
```

And annotation:

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LoggingRest {
    String executor() default "SYSTEM";
    String method() default "";
    String model() default "";

}
```

Comment: You can use AOP.

Comment: You can implement your own annotation, aspect and interceptor for this case.

Comment: @Karthikeyan thank you very much for your answer. Can you give an example, what words to search on google?

Comment: @Simon Search for Spring AOP.

Answer (score 1):

Auditing is a `cross-cutting` concern and can be handled using AOP.

Another solution would be to use a low-level solution by writing a custom annotation and using a `Spring interceptor`to write your business logic.

To use the `Spring interceptor` you will need to implement the `HandlerInterceptor` `interface`

Example of the annotation

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Audit {
    boolean active() default true;
}
```

Interceptor example

```
@Component
public class AuditInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Override
  public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex)
      throws Exception {

    if (handler instanceof HandlerMethod) {

      HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handler;
      Audit annotation = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(Audit.class);

       if (annotation != null && annotation.active()) {
           // your business logic
       }
     }
     HandlerInterceptor.super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);

}
```

check this interceptor [example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_boot/spring_boot_interceptor.htm)

Comment: Thank you very much, it became much clearer to me. This is my first time with the AOP paradigm.
But still I have some questions, which I described in the comment below with code examples. If possible, please take a look.

Comment: My solution is without using AOP libraries, is only with core java with Spring. Please upvote if you find it useful.

Comment: It is very useful. Of corse I upvoted

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the solutions here, as @Karthikeyan mentioned, is to use Spring AOP.

If you are not aware a brief introduction - spring-aop module implements the aspect oriented programming paradigm. We extract some common functionality, that we generally want to apply to some subset of functions/methods, to an entity called `Aspect` (see class annotated with `@Aspect`). This class will contain out cross-cutting functionality - such as auditing, for instance we want to audit the methods execution time, lets say. We just put the code to be executed, the condition, which tell the spring what exact beans methods should be affect by this aspect, see below.

For example, if I can audit the method execution duration with the following very simple example (in my case I said that any `public` method, returning `void` inside the Class `com.example.stackoverflow.BusinessLogicClass` must be inspected by this Aspect):

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class StackoverflowApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    @Autowired
    private BusinessLogicClass businessLogicClass;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(StackoverflowApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        businessLogicClass.test();
    }
}

@Aspect
@Component
class MyAspectLogicClass {

    @Around("execution(public void com.example.stackoverflow.BusinessLogicClass.*(..))")
    public Object hangAround(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) throws Throwable {
        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object returnedValue = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.printf("Retruned in '%s' ms %n", (after - before));
        return returnedValue;
    }
}

@Component
class BusinessLogicClass {

    public void test() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In my case, I will get the time before method execution, then by the means of
**proceedingJoinPoint.proceed()** call I delegate the execution to the real method, and then, once I get the response back, I will get the current system time and calculate the execution time, fairly simple.

I hope I have at least directed you somewhere, if you are looking for documentation, this are the resources I suggest you should look for:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html  offical spring doc (stale a bit, but there are some valuable things to learn)
- https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html is more fresh doc

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Thank you very much, it became much clearer to me. This is my first time with the AOP paradigm.
But still I have some questions, which I described in the comment below with code examples. If possible, please take a look.

Comment: I have updated a question in the post

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in right annotation. In Aspect class I tried `@Around` and everything works as I need.

```
@Aspect
@Slf4j
@Component
public class AuditAspect {

    @Around(value = "@annotation(com.aspect.annotations.LoggingRest)")
    public void auditMethod(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint) {
        var method = ((MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();
        log.info("----------ASPECT METHOD IS CALLED------------");
    }
}
```

For getting a Method instance I use fallowing code

```
Method method = ((MethodSignature) proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature()).getMethod();
```